# Derivative of a function with respect to a lower triangular matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a scalar-valued function $f$ defined on the space of $n \times n$ matrices. I have an analytic expression for the gradient, $\nabla f$.

Now, suppose I define a function, $g$, on the space of lower triangular matrices as $g(L) := f(LL^T)$. I'd like to derive an analytic expression for the gradient of  $g$. I assume some sort of chain rule should go through so that I can get a rather simple expression using $\nabla f$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's suppose that $$H(L) = LL^T,$$ so $$\frac{\partial g(L)}{\partial L} = \frac{\partial f(H)}{\partial H}\frac{\partial H(L)}{\partial L}$$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll go with the answer by @greg, due to its level of detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing, denote the gradients of $f(X)$ and $g(L)$ as
$$\eqalign{
F &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = \nabla f \\
G &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial L} \\
}$$
First, calculate the differential of $X$ in terms of $L$.
$$\eqalign{
X &= LL^T \quad\implies\quad dX = dL\,L^T + L\,dL^T \\
}$$
Then write the differential of the function and perform a change of variables from
$X\to L$.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= df \\
 &= F:dX \\
 &= F:(dL\,L^T+L\,dL^T) \\
 &= (F+F^T):(dL\,L^T) \\
 &= (F+F^T)L:dL \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial L} &= (F+F^T)L \;=\; G \\
\\
}$$
In the above, a colon is used as a product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A}$$
The terms in such a product can be rearranged in a number of equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
}$$
due to the properties of the trace function.

Comment: This is perfect-clean and simple. Thanks a lot. May I ask what your favorite textbook/source on such topic is?

Comment: Just for the record, I didn't make it clear in the question at all, but I was viewing $L$ as an $n(n+1)/2$ vector. Hence, I'm taking the lower triangular part of $(F + F^T)L$ (and make it to a vector) as the derivative in my project. Everything's working like a charm. Thanks!